# Partial functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm still confused on what a partial function is.

If I have a domain and codomain of integers from $-10^6$ to $10^6$, what are some partial functions that work with this domain and codomain? What are some that don't?

I know for example that $x^2$ is not a function within these restrictions because if I put in $10^6$, I get $10^{12}$ out, which is out of my interval.

If someone could describe in layman's terms some partial functions and what makes them partial that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the square of $10^6$ lays outside the co-domain actually makes $x^2$ a fine example of a partial function: apparently we cannot define the function value for all of the objects in the domain, and thus the function is a partial function.

For an alternative example, take $f(x)=x+1$ which will be defined for all numbers in the domain except for $10^6$, for which the function is undefined. This function is therefore also a partial function.

Comment: Okay so I'm working on a programming assignment that does this. I am inputting into a function all integer values from the domain of x. If I get a number back that is outside the codomain, the function is still a partial function? So it doesn't matter what I get as output? Or does at least one of the outputs have to be defined for the whole function to be a partial function?

Comment: The only valid outputs of a function are those in the codomain. If you *would* get an output outside that codomain, then it means you do not have a valid output for the function, therefore the function does not have an output for one of its inputs, and is therefore partial.

Comment: So if all the outputs I get are not in the codomain, is the function still partial?

Comment: @Coder117 You never get an output that is not in the codomain. So, for my example of $f(x)=x+1$, $f(10^6)$ is not defined, i.e. There is no output in that case ... Which is exactly what makes it a partial function.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but is it possible to have a function where no matter what I put in for x, I never get an output that fits within my codomain? If so, is that function a partial function? Or not at all? For example is f(x) = x + 10^12 + 1 a partial function even though when I put in my lower bound of my domain f(-10^6) I still get out 10^6 + 1 which is not in my codomain?

Comment: @Coder117 A function that is not defined for *any* object of its domain would still be considered a partial function, yes.

Comment: Wow that's crazy. Haha thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Coder117 Well, any function that is not total is partial, so it does fit the definition, crazy as it is :) Glad I could help!

Comment: @Bram28 Sorry, just to be absolutely sure: There isn't any function then that would not be a partial function with my domain and codomain? Something I am working on is determining whether or not a function is partial or not, so I'm confused on why I would have to do that if every function is partial.

Comment: @Coder117 Oh, you can certainly have a total (i.e. Not partial) function with your domain and codomain: $f(x)=x$ will do nicely!

Comment: @Bram28 great thanks again

Comment: In Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs by K. Kunen, a partial function from $A$ to $B$ is a function $f:C\to B$ for some (any) $C\subset A.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That's a nice definition, thanks!  And with $C = \emptyset$, you see that a function that is undefined for all objects in $A$ is a partial function as well ... unless $A$ itself is the empty set: any function defined over the empty set is automatically a total function.